# Twitter Bootstrap + Google Maps still doesn't work with bug fix

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

I have a google maps in my html page:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
          <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
          <h3>Heading</h3>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
```

My javascript map settings:

```
 var settingsItemsMap = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.056703, 3.719999),
    zoomControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), settingsItemsMap );
```

I know that I have to add this to my css file:

```
#map_canvas img{
  max-width: none;
}
```

But I still doesn't show anything! Am I missing something?

Comment: I would fire up the dev tools in chrome, firebug in Firefox etc. or whatever browser do you use and look at the console output... There are surely some hints, maybe you are missing some imports. You could also create a jsfiddle so we can look at the hole problem.

Comment: Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5UdxJ/
Looked again and I can't find an answer. Only if I do:
#map_canvas{ 
height:300px;
width:400px;
}

it works. But that's not the solution ...

Comment: I'm afraid you are required to set the height and width of your "map_canvas" the google maps API does not calculate your div's dimension automatically I guess, you have to do it yourself depending on your layout.

Comment: $(window).resize(function () {
    var h = $(window).height(),
        offsetTop = 190; // Calculate the top offset

    $('#map_canvas').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
}).resize();

did the trick for me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var h = $(window).height(),
        offsetTop = 190; // Calculate the top offset

    $('#map_canvas').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
}).resize();
```

This did the trick for me!